# Detect if window.open will replace the current page instead of opening a window?

Tags: javascript, popup, window.open

In many iOS apps that have WebViews, using JavaScript's `window.open` method will load the attempted popup window in the main window instead, losing everything that was in memory in the opening page. Is there a way to detect that `window.open()` will do this instead of its intended functionality of opening a separate page?

Comment: Are you even specifying a target for this `window.open()`? Because targetting to `_blank` should always open to a new tab.

Comment: Yes, but when you're in (for example) the Facebook App for iOS's internal browser, there aren't tabs. In that case `window.open` opens the page in the current "tab" even if you specify `_blank`.